# Bound truncated convolution

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, convolution

Let $f$ be a continuous stochastic process bounded in $L^p(\Omega)$, i.e., $\mathbb E|f(t)|^p \leq C$ for all $t\geq 0$, $g \in L^\infty(\mathbb R) \cap C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ for all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ with support in $[0, \infty)$. Let the convolution be defined as
$$
F(t) = (f \star g)(t) =\int_0^t f(s)g(t-s)ds.
$$
I would like to bound, for all $p \geq 1$, the quantity $\mathbb E|F(t)|^p$. I looked into Young's inequality for convolutions, which gives for $p,q,r \geq 1$ such that $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1 + r^{-1}$,
$$
\| F\|_r \leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q.
$$
Now, choosing $r = \infty$, we have for all $t > 0$ and a generic constant $C$
$$
\mathbb E |F(t)|^p \leq \int_0^t \mathbb E|f(s)|^p ds \left(\int_0^t |g(s)|^q ds \right)^{p-1} \leq Ct.
$$
Since the convolution should be a "smoother version" of $f$, I would have guessed to find a bound independent of time, i.e., that $\mathbb E |F(t)|^p \leq C$.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I forgot the assumption 
$$
\int_0^t |g(s)|^p ds \leq C 
$$
for all $p \geq 1$.

Comment: where did you get $Ct$ from? I get a $Ct$ from $\int_0^t \mathbb{E}|f(s)|^pds$; but what about the $(\int_0^t |g(s)|^qds)^{p-1}$? Doesn't that give a $C^{p-1}$?

Comment: Anyways, the answer to your question is that "smoothness" refers to derivatives, not size. Note that if $g \equiv 1$, then $F$ is the integral of $f$, so a bound of $C$ changes to a bound of $Ct$.

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved the problem by assuming that $g$ "almost" integrates to $1$ over $(0, t)$, so that one can apply Jensen's inequality. For the constant $C$, it was a "line-changing" constant